# in opengl why do we have to do gluPerspective before gluLookAt?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, matrix-multiplication, perspectivecamera

so under GL_PROJECTION I did

```
    glu.gluPerspective(90,aspect,1,10);
    glu.gluLookAt(0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,0);
```

this works fine but when I switch the order I don't get any object on my screen, I rotated my camera and theres nothing.

I know that switching the two changes the order of matrix multiplication but I want to know why the first case works but the second doesn't. Thanks

Comment: Aside: `GL_PROJECTION` should only have projection transforms, both model and view transforms should go in `GL_MODELVIEW`. Although it'll work, it's the right thing to do, a convention to be followed.

Comment: What @legends2k said. Also putting viewing transforms into GL_PROJECTION will cause problems as soon as lighting enters the scene.

Comment: ["Help stamp out GL_PROJECTION abuse."](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/projection_abuse.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see an object on screen you need it to fall within the canonical view volume, which is, for OpenGL, [−1, 1] in all three dimensions. To transform an object, you roughly do

> P' = Projection × View × Model × P

where `P'` is the final point which needs to be in the canonical view volume and P is the initial point in model space. P is transformed by the model matrix followed by view and then projection.

The order I've followed is column vector based, where each further transform is pre/left-multiplied. Another way to read the same formula is to read it from left-to-right where instead of transforming the point, the coordinate system is transformed and interpreting `P` in the transformed system spatially represents `P'` in the original system. This is just another way to see it, the result is the same in both; both numerically and spatially.

> why do we have to do gluPerspective before gluLookAt?

The older, fixed-function pipeline *OpenGL post/right-multiplies* and thus the order needs to be reversed to get the same effect. So when we need *LookAt* first and *Perspective* next, we do the reverse to get the expected result.

Giving the two in right order leads to

> P' = View × Projection × Model × P

since matrix multiplication is anti-commutative, you don't get the right `P'` which falls within the canonical view volume and hence black screen.

See the [Chapter 3, Red Book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html), under the section *General-Purpose Transformation Commands* which explains the order followed by OpenGL. Excerpt:

> **Note:** All matrix multiplication with OpenGL occurs as follows: Suppose the current matrix is **C** and the matrix specified with *glMultMatrix*()* or any of the transformation commands is **M**. After multiplication, the final matrix is always **CM**. Since matrix multiplication isn't generally commutative, the order makes a difference.

---

> I want to know why the first case works but the second doesn't.

To know what really happens with the matrix formed of incorrect order, lets do a small workout in 2D. Lets say the canonical view *region* is [−100, 100] in both X and Y; anything outside this is clipped out. The origin of this imaginary square screen is at the centre, X goes right, Y goes up. When no transform is applied calling `DrawImage` draws the image at the origin. You've an image which is 1 × 1; its model matrix is scaling by `200` so that it becomes a `200 × 200` image; one that fills the entire screen. Since origin is at centre of the screen, to draw the image such that it fills the screen, we need a view matrix that translates (moves) the image by (−100, −100). Formulating this

> P' = View × Model = Translate<sub>−100, −100</sub> × Scale<sub>200, 200</sub>

```
[ 200,  0,  −100 ]
[  0,  200, −100 ]
[  0,   0,   1   ]
```

However, the result of

> Model × View = S<sub>200, 200</sub> × T<sub>−100, −100</sub>

```
[ 200,  0,  −20000 ]
[  0,  200, −20000 ]
[  0,   0,    1    ]
```

Multiplying the former matrix with points (0, 0) and (1, 1) would result in (−100, −100) and (100, 100) as expected. The image corners would be aligned to the screen corners. However, multiplying the latter matrix with them would result in (−20000, −20000) and (−19800, −19800); well outside the viewable region. This is because, geometrically, the latter matrix first translates and then scales as opposed to scaling and then translating. The translated scale leads to a point that is completely off.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I understand that changing the order changes the order of matrix multiplication. Is it possible to elaborate a bit more on why it doesn't fall into the canonical view? (I know P*V*M is the correct order and changing the order gives an incorrect matrix but what is this wrong matrix implying?) Thank you

Comment: Please check the updated answer which now contains an example to make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

In the

```
glu.gluPerspective(90,aspect,1,10);
glu.gluLookAt(0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,0);
```

case, first model/world coordinates (in R^3) are transformed into view coordinates (also R^3). Then the projection maps the view coordinates to a perspective space (P^4), which is then reduced by the perspective divide to NDC coordinates. This is in general how it should work.

Now have a look at:

```
glu.gluLookAt(0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,0);
glu.gluPerspective(90,aspect,1,10);
```

Here, world coordinates are projected directly in projective space (P^4). Since the lookAt matrix is a mapping from R^3 -> R^3 and we are already in P^4, this is not going to work. Even if it would be possible to rotate the P^4, the parameters of gluLookAt would have to be adapted to fit to the ranges of the projective space.

Note: In general one should never add gluLookAt to the GL_PROJECTION stack. Since it describes the view matrix it better fits to the GL_MODELVIEW stack. For reference have a look [here](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm).